# Python Pymem Error 299 not getting any value of the pointer address

Tags: python, pointers, pointer-address

So i tried a code to read a pointer address for a game. I used pymem to red the pointer but i get the error 299 and i kinda dont find a solution for my problem

````
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import module_from_name
from pymem.ptypes import *
from pymem.ptypes import RemotePointer



pm = Pymem("BloonsTD6.exe")
gameModule = module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "GameAssembly.dll").lpBaseOfDll
#gameModule = "GameAssembly.dll"


offsets = [0x020, 0x0B8, 0x000, 0x0F0, 0x170, 0x088, 0x348]

def getPointerAddress(base, offsets):
    remote_pointer = RemotePointer(pm.process_handle, base + 0x0336F960)
    for offset in offsets:
        if offset != offsets[-1]:
            remote_pointer = RemotePointer(pm.process_handle, remote_pointer.value + offset)  #<--- Error 299
        else:
            return remote_pointer.value + offset




print(pm.read_longlong(getPointerAddress(pm.base_address, offsets)))
print(getPointerAddress(pm.base_address, offsets))

from ctypes import string_at
from sys import getsizeof

a = 0x0334ADB8
print(string_at(id(a),getsizeof(a)).hex())```




I also tried with c++ and ReadWriteMemory but i get the same error 299. Can i somehow specify the problem more so i can get another output then error 299 or does anyone know how i can fix the error?
````